# Best practice for repeatedly initializing a class with identical parameters (Pyramid)?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, initialization, dry

I want to streamline/reduce my code, so I try to put initializations of classes with repeated parameters in their own, extended classes. This is a REST API based on Pyramid & Cornice.

How would I initialize a [pyramid.httpexceptions.HTTPUnauthorized](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/httpexceptions.html#pyramid.httpexceptions.HTTPUnauthorized) when I'm always adding the same headers on initialization? This also applies to other HTTP responses where I initialize them repeatedly without changing their parameters.

Currently I've come up with this to extend the class:

```py
class _401(HTTPUnauthorized):
    def basic_jwt_header(self):
        self.headers.add('WWW-Authenticate','JWT')
        self.headers.add('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Please log in"')
        return self

    def jwt_header(self):
        self.headers.add('WWW-Authenticate','JWT')
        return self
```

which I use in a view like this:

```py
@forbidden_view_config()
def authenticate(request):
    response = _401()
    return _401.basic_jwt_header(response)
```

But it does not feel and look right. Is there a better, cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using two different methods after instantiating your `_401` instance, then you might be better off using class-level factory methods, which will do both the instance creation *and* setting the desired headers:

```
class _401(HTTPUnauthorized):

    @classmethod
    def basic_jwt_header(cls):
        ret = cls()
        ret.headers.add('WWW-Authenticate','JWT')
        ret.headers.add('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Please log in"')
        return ret

    @classmethod
    def jwt_header(cls):
        ret = cls()
        ret.headers.add('WWW-Authenticate','JWT')
        return ret

resp = _401.basic_jwt_header()
print resp.headers
```

Now there's no need for creating `__init__`, or calling `super()` or whatever.  We use `cls` instead of the explicit `_401` class in support of any future subclassing of `_401`.

Comment: That looks tidier than adding an argument and condition-query to the __init__()!

Answer (score 2):

Create an `__init__` method on the class:

```
class _401(HTTPUnauthorized):

    def __init__(self):
        # call base class __init__ first, which will set up the
        # headers instance variable
        super(_401, self).__init__()
        # in Python 3, just use this:
        # super().__init__()

        # now add the headers that you always enter
        self.headers.add('WWW-Authenticate','JWT')
        self.headers.add('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Please log in"')

resp = _401()
print resp.headers
```

Comment: Ah, `super()` is the magic glue! Even nicer in Python3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/576183/570722 - maybe you could add that info?